# How do you handle redirecting upon authentication on Android?

Tags: android, authentication

I'm currently building out a ICS 4.0+ Android app that will require authentication. The issue I'm having is handling checking for login status when:

- User first opens the app
- User returns to app after closing (resuming)

The behavior I'm looking for is that there is a "loading..." splash screen if the app is removed from memory and reopened, and then an almost unnoticeable splash screen when the user returns to app upon resuming (still in memory).

The code I currently have for checking this is:

```
    public static void checkUserStatus(Context context, boolean isPassive) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Checking user status..");
    // User is logged in and has cc
    if ( APIUtil.isLoggedIn() && UserAccount.getCreditCards().size() > 0 && isPassive == false) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, OtherActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    // User is logged in but has no cc
    } else if (APIUtil.isLoggedIn() && UserAccount.getCreditCards().size() == 0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ManageCCActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    // User is not logged in
    } else if(isPassive == false) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

checkUserStatus is called in onResume() of every activity. The idea being that it'll check this and redirect accordingly, but the behavior is wacky and inconsistent and it just feels janky.

Are there any examples of authentication flow out there? Ideas? Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pattern that I've used and seen other use that works well looks something like this:

- Encapsulate the logic you have for determining if the user is logged in and has valid data into a `Service`, and then run that `Service` bound (meaning you never start or stop it, you bind to it...[docs link for more on that](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#CreatingBoundService)).
- Implement a base `Activity` implementation that binds to the service in `onStart()` and unbinds froms it in `onStop()`.  This allows the `Service` to stay running as you move from one `Activity` to another.  Have any `Activity` that needs access to this information inherit from this base (which may be every `Activity`).
- Have the `Service` check the information it needs to only when it starts up, and call back with the results.

What this creates is a (fairly) single instance of checking for authorization that only checks when the application starts up or the user returns after leaving it, without constantly checking as you move from one `Activity` to another.  It also allows it to gracefully finish any long-running operations if the user leaves prematurely since all the work is being done in a `Service`.

Comment: This is interesting... This maybe the way to go, but is there a easier way of funneling all resume/launching app behaviors through a single Activity and can detect status and reroute accordingly?

Comment: Not really without constructing your application out of a single Activity and doing the subdivision using Fragments, which isn't really recommended.  Android is designed purposefully without the singular concept of an "application" from the perspective of the user moving in and out, so you have to use a component like a `Service` to tie the pieces of your UI together.

Comment: Didn't necessarily lead to this, but excellent answer and suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i'm doing right now on an application i've been developing.

1) StartUpActivity: Checks wether the user is logged in or not. Redirects to Login screen or main screen depending on the user status. You might want to add a silent login if the user saved it's credentials and there's a need for some sort of api token, or session.

2) In my app, the user has to be logged in because it's accessing some protected resources. If the resource can not be accessed, because of an invalid api token, or incorrect login information, then an intent is broadcasted from the API/Network level ( usually matches http codes 401 or 403 )

3) The BroadcastReceiver catches that specific intent, logs out the user, and redirects the app the the login screen with a message.

This way your UI doesn't have to check for the user status, it just needs to be ready to be taken out of the screen whenever the user gets unauthorized.

Is worth commenting that my app does use the network quite often, since it's a near real time app. Because of this, i'm able to catch unauthorized events rather quickly.

Comment: So when the user launches for the first time, it goes to StartUpActivity. But what happens when the user resumes? Or does your app always go there first?

Comment: No, my app can go on the background without problems. I have a service that performs api calls periodically, therefore i'm able to tell whether the user still has valid credentials. Maybe it would help if you explain what is your app about, what things has to be protected, and how often does the user access to them.

Comment: The app is a classic "must have account and credit card to use" app, however, the security doesn't need to be bank level. My goal is for the user to a see a quick intermediate screen when resuming verifying they're logged in, then redirect accordingly. The flow would go: 1) user pauses app, 2) user resumes app, 3) user is presented "Checking status..." screen, 4) user is redirect either to login or previous activity

Comment: How do you detect if a user have invalid login information? is there any other event that you can use instead of having to manually check everytime the user goes back to your app? I don't think what you are doing is wrong, i would just do it in the background. Go straight to the activity where the user was, and instead of calling checkUserStatus, create another thread that does it and notifies back to the UI. If the user is correctly logged in, then he/she won't even notice anything. Otherwise you can notify the user and/or redirect him to the login screen